# Reputation and topic gone

Tags: support

Yesterday I answered a question from a guy who was wondering about his website being displayed incorrectly on different browsers, especially the mobile ones (like Safari on iPhone).

I answered his question with my best intentions and put quite a thought into my reply. Therefore I got already 4 ups/likes (don´t know how to call em) after a short period of time. But when I logged into stackoverflow this morning my at least 40 reputation gained through the answer were gone, as well as the whole question itself, including any notifications in my inbox, comments etc., every track of the question is gone.

My questions now is: What happened? Can a question be removed completely, even undoing the reputation it has delivered to some guy and everything else that has happened because of it? If so, by whom and under what conditions?

I was/am kind of angry, I didn't get any notification about what happened, it's just gone, even the (in my opinion) useful question and answer.

I don´t know if that has happened to anyone else before or was just a bug because of some kind of update in the last hours - maybe this is supposed to be directed to the support, but I feel right to ask/post it this way (if it isn´t, please tell ;) - maybe the fact that I can´t find any suitable tag is an indicator it is the wrong way).

Comment: Duplicate of [many] questions on Meta. You can lose reputation for any number of reasons. Question deleted or moved to another SO site, for instance. Uses completely deleted, removing all their questions and answers, etc. The vote fraud detector might have kicked in and removed some votes, etc.

Comment: yes, it  happened to me too :)

Comment: The deleted question in question: [Website layout is breaking in apples's ios iphone browser only](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17136869/1114)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You answered an exceedingly low-quality question.

> I am developing a site http://recherchefineart.com/. But it is showing great in all browser like Chrome, firefox , I E , but it is breaking in apple's ipad browser , iphone browser etc. You can check it on http://www.testiphone.com/ and then typing the url. Can anyone help me in this matter.

[The same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103906/site-breaking-in-safari-browser) by the same user had been posted, closed and deleted a few days earlier.  Since they don't seem interested in improving the question, I just deleted the copy without waiting around.  Don't be surprised when your answers to questions of this quality are deleted.

Comment: okay, i´m still not happy with it - what you are saying is, that i should not answer to low quality questons!?

Comment: @luk2302 I wouldn't bother answering a question that is that bad.

Answer (score 0):

When a question is removed, its answers are gone, too, and so is all reputation associated with them (I don't know if this affects bounties, though).